# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I keep getting this error when making calls to my native methods compiled in an .SO file.
i dont why its happening since everything seems to be set up right
any help would be appreciated

error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: de.jurihock.voicesmith.dsp.Math.abs:(FF)F
at de.jurihock.voicesmith.dsp.Math.abs(Native Method)
```

cpp file: [pastebin.com/aBHNz642](http://pastebin.com/aBHNz642)

Math.java

```
 package de.jurihock.voicesmith.dsp;

public final class Math
{
     static
        {
        System.loadLibrary("Voicesmith");
        }

public static final float   PI  = (float) java.lang.Math.PI;

public static int round(float value)
{
    return java.lang.Math.round(value);
}

public static native float pow(float base, float exponent);

public static native float log10(float value);

public static native float min(float a, float b);

public static native float max(float a, float b);

public static native float floor(float value);

public static native float ceil(float value);

public static native float sin(float angle);

public static native float cos(float angle);

public static native float sqrt(float value);

public static native float atan2(float y, float x);

public  native float abs(float real, float imag);

public static native float arg(float real, float imag);

public static native float real(float abs, float arg);

public static native float imag(float abs, float arg);

public static native float random(float min, float max);

public static native float princarg(float phase);

public static native short mean(short[] buffer, int offset, int length);

public static native float rms(short[] buffer, int offset, int length);

public static native float rms(short[] buffer, int offset, int length, short mean);

public static native float rms2dbfs(float value, float min, float max);
```

}

android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Name of the library without prefix "lib" and file extension
LOCAL_MODULE := Voicesmith

# Optimization flags (see KissFFT makefile)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer

# LogCat support
# LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

# Debugging flag
# LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g

# Include all .c/.cpp files to build
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(shell cd $(LOCAL_PATH); \
    find . -type f -name '*.c'; \
    find . -type f -name '*.cpp')

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: is the Math.java in the correct package?

Comment: yes. it is in the package de.jurihock.voicesmith.dsp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your native method `abs` is missing `static` in its declaration. Your build should have caught the error, Android Studio does..

Try changing it to

`public static native float abs(float real, float imag);`

Some other suggestions:

- name `Math.h` can conflict with standard `math.h` on native side (wont even compile if you try on windows, as windows file system is case insensitive ... i had to change your Math.h to Math2.h).
- Even on java side, there is already `Math` class at `java.lang.Math` with similar functions (eg: `java.lang.Math.abs`), can potentially autocomplete with `java.lang.Math.abs` particularly for your code snippet above as it misses `static` in declaration (``java.lang.Math.abs` is static IDE matches to it)

Comment: I had removed the static in an attempt to figure out if that was the problem . I'll put it back and try the other two suggestions. Thankyou.